# Android programmatically add string id

Tags: android, checkbox

I need to programmatically add id's to new checkboxes.

I tried :  `checkBox.setId("black_eyes");`

But I receive the int error.

Then I tried : `checkBox.setId(Integer.parseInt("black_eyes"));`

Here I received the string to int error

I have to populate a LinearLayout with checkboxes that I received from an API and I need to show it pro grammatically. I need to set string id on them.

If it's not possible, then how can I add new strings to resources file (string.xml) ?

Comment: you can add new string like:  <string name="new_string">MyString</string>.

Comment: Please learn java basics. Then you can be clear towards your requirement

Answer (score 2):

When using `checkBox.setId("black_eyes");` you receive an error because the method expect an `int` and you provide a `String`.

When using `Integer.parseInt("black_eyes")` you have an error because this method try to parse the `String` as an `int`. For example `Integer.parseInt("5")` will return the `5` (as an `int`). In your case `black_eyed` can not be parsed as an `int`.

You can use the `setTag` method of the `View` class. Call `checkBox.setTag("black_eyes")` will work. Then you can retrieve the tag of the checkbox using `checkBox.getTag()`. This method return a `Object` so you add to cast it `String tag = (String) checkBox.getTag()`.

PS : You can not add new strings in string.xml at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using sonic answer. I will put here how i manage it, maybe someone will use :

First i create an ArrayList of type Checkbox

```
private static List<CheckBox> eyes_views =  new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

Then i create the checkboxes from api ws programmatically like this :

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) activitate.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_checkbox, null);
         checkBox.setTag(ws_flag);
         checkBox.setText(ws_name);
```

After that i add the new checkbox to the layout and stored in the ArrayList :

```
list_views.add(checkBox);
eyes_views.addView(checkBox);
```

And finaly when i what to seach only for those checked :

```
for (CheckBox checkbox : eyes_views)
{
    if (checkbox.isChecked())
    {
         eyes=eyes.concat(checkbox.getTag()+",");
    }
}
```

Hope it will help others!